# changes at SmugMug appear to have blown up pysmug

Tags: django, pycurl

Anyone else wrestling with changes instituted at SmugMug the week before Thanksgiving that have resulted in "invalid user" errors when using pysmug and Django?

There's a suggestion that they are now requiring the presence of an _su cookie, but it seems to me pycurl used in pysmug ought to handle this properly.

The error does not occur on login, so I'm assuming the error message "invalid user" is bogus.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having pysmug trouble the following patch fixed the issue:

pysmug's implementation of pycurl does not set a cookie jar. To fix the problem, add the following two lines to smugmug.py at line number #143 and reinstall:

```
c.setopt(c.COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt')
c.setopt(c.COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt')
```

You may want to set an absolute path to cookies.txt to make sure it's getting written to a folder with the necessary permissions, i.e. /tmp/